# GASのコードでSpreadSheetのセルの数式IMPORTRANGEで取得されているものを置き換えて値として貼り付けたい

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

タイトルの通りなのですが、あまりデータの範囲が広くないシートの場合は下記コードで正常に動きます。

A1セルにIMPORTRANGEの数式が入っている場合に、そこから全セルの値を取得してそれをsetValuesすることで、A1セルは値になり、他のすべてのセルの値も残ります。

```
  const values = sheet.getRange(
    1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn()
  ).getValues();

  sheet.getRange(
    1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn()
  ).setValues(values);
```

ですが、より大きなシートになるとsetValuesの途中で6分間の制限にひっかかってしまい、データのすべてがセルに残らなくなってしまうのです。

より高速にとか簡単にGASで、A1セルのIMPORTRANGEの式で取得できた内容をすべて保持しながらA1セルの数式を消すことはできないでしょうか？

単純にA1セルを空白にすると、当然ですがIMPORTRANGEでもってこれていた値はすべて消えてしまいます。

よろしくおねがいします。

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました。

setValues は意外と低速で数十列の万単位行だとタイムアウトしますが
次のようにすると数分で処理が終わりました。

- シートをすべてコピーしてバックアップシートにする。当然IMPORTRANGE部分もコピーされる。
- 元シートのIMPORTRANGEの数式を削除する(そのシートのデータは全部消える)
- バックアップシートから元シートへ、range.copyTo(range) を行う。数値のみのコピーなど指定可能。
- バックアップシートを削除する

このようにすると、IMPORTRANGEで表示されていたものがIMPORTRANGEをけして値として取得することができます。
これで2,3,4分くらいかかりますが、動作範囲内で処理が終わりました。

もっとよい方法がありましたら、記載いただけたら助かります。よろしくおねがいします。